# Check if analog value is within threshold

Tags: c, threshold

I'm reading an analogue value from a Pin on a µC.
I want to check periodically if the value has changed more than `x`.
Here, I am using the `abs()` function, but I want to keep it simple. 
Can you help me?

```
int algVal= 0;
int oldVal = 0

while(1){

  algVal = getAlgVal();

  if(abs(algVal - oldVal) > x)
   {
    doStuff();
   }

  oldVal= algVal:

}
```

Comment: How much simpler do you want this to get? It's gonna be difficult.

Comment: I don't see how much simpler it can get. What do you need help with?

Comment: Is it the "periodically" that you require help with or the implementation of `getAlgVal()`?.

Comment: The only problem that I forsee is that your code will remain in the while loop. 

This could be a problem if you need to do anything else with your processor, other than check this input pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds like a fantastic approach, and would probably be very nice in terms of runtime performance, `abs()` for integers is cheap. If in doubt, read the generated assembly of course.